# Can you disallow a common lisp script called from common lisp to call specific functions?

Tags: security, permissions, common-lisp

Common Lisp allows to execute/compile code at runtime. But I thought for some (scripting-like) purposes it would be good if one could disallow a user-script to call some functions (especially for application extensions). One could still ask the user if he will allow an extension to access files/... I'm thinking of something like the Android permission system for Common Lisp. Is this possible without rewriting the evaluation code?
The problem I see is, that in Common Lisp you would probably want a script to be able to use reader macros and normal macros and for the latter operators like `intern`, but those would allow you to get arbitrary symbols (by string manipulation & interning), so simply scanning the code before evaluation won't suffice to ensure that specific functions aren't called.
So, is there something like a lock for functions? I thought of using `fmakunbound` / `makunbound` (and keeping the values in a local variable), but would that be possible in a multi-threaded environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not part of the Common Lisp specification and there is no Common Lisp implementation that is extended to make this kind of restriction easy.

It seems to me like it would be easier to use operating system restrictions (e.g. rlimit, capabilities, etc) to enforce what you want on the Common Lisp process.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an unusual desire, i.e. to run untrusted 3rd party code in a sandbox.

You can hand craft a sandbox by creating a custom parser and interpreter for your scripting language.  It is pedantic, but true, than any program with an API is providing such a service. API designers and implementors needs to worry about the vile users.

You can still call eval or the compiler to run your sandbox scripts.  It just means you need to assure that your reader, parser and language decline to provide access to any risky functionality.

You can use a lisp package to create a good sandbox.  You can still use s-expressions for your scripting language's syntax, but you must cripple the standard reader so the user can't escape package-sandbox.    You can still use the evaluator and the compiler, but you need to be sure the package you have boxed the user into contains no functionality that he can use to do inappropriate things.

Successful sandbox design and construction is easier when you start with an empty sandbox and slowly add functionality.  Common Lisp is a big language and that creates a huge surface for attacker to poke at.  So if you create a sandbox out of a package it's best to start with an empty package and add functions one at a time.  Thinking thru what risks they create.   The same approach is good when creating your crippled reader.  Don't start with the full reader and throw things away, start with a useless reader and add things.  Sadly taking that advice creates a pretty significant cost to getting started.  But, if you look around I suspect you can find an existing safe reader.

Xach's suggestion is another way to go and in many case more straight forward.